# Wordpress User Registration from c-panel with notification mail

Tags: wordpress, email, cpanel

User is registered in my WordPress application but we need to create new email account of registered user from cpanel(with the same domain name we use for WordPress application).

User also get the notification on new created email on cpanel after he registered to my WordPress site from the application.

Basically I want to integrate cpanel email creation facility from the my WordPress application.

Any such API or Plugin exist for it?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Following plugins might helpful

https://wordpress.org/plugins/cpanel-e-mail-manager/

https://wordpress.org/plugins/cpanel-manager-from-worpit/

Hope this helps you!!!